# Dump class/struct member variables in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Is there a flag in `g++` or tools to dump the *member variables* of a struct/class? To illustrate, consider source code like this

```
struct A { virtual void m() {}; };
struct B : public A { int b; virtual void n() = 0; };
struct C : public B { int c1, c2; void o(); };
struct D : public C { virtual void n() {}; A d; };
```

I want to get something similar to

```
A:   0 = (vptr)

B:   0 = (vptr)
     4 = b

C:   0 = (vptr)
     4 = b
     8 = c1
    12 = c2

D:   0 = (vptr)
     4 = b
     8 = c1
    12 = c2
    16 = d
```

(`-fdump-class-hierarchy` does not work. It only prints the member functions.)

(Assume I don't know the classes `A` to `D`, or there are so many classes that I don't want to list them out myself.)

(Specifically, I want to dump the member variables of http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/iokit/IOKit/IOUserClient.h).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the right tool for the right job. g++ isn't much of a hierarchy viewing tool.

You can always use a external tool like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/), that can dump [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) diagrams.

For power-solutions there is [gcc-xml](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html), that can dump your whole program into an xml file that you can parse at will.

Comment: Thanks! `gcc-xml` works for me, although I still need to write a not-so-small script to convert it back to the form I need. (http://networkpx.googlecode.com/svn/etc/print-struct-members.py in case anyone interested.)

Answer (score 2):

I would use ddd, then display the structs in the data pane.  You can expand an individual struct that points to another struct and the UI will follow from one to the other.  A very powerful debugging tool.

Comment: Thanks. But that requires me to list all the structs. Furthermore, some structs are unfortunately abstract so I can't `new` them.

Comment: +1.  Sometimes the code is too complex/obfuscated for [Doxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) to make any sense of it, but the debugger will hopefully still work.  I had more luck accessing complex structures with [Nemiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemiver) than with [kdbg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDbg).  [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Display_Debugger) is also an intriguing option, but the UI takes some getting used to.