# Is there any g++ option to dump class layout and vtables?

Tags: c++, g++

I want to see how g++ lays out memory for classes and virtual tables.

Is there a way to dump this information, using g++'s options?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123823/dump-class-struct-member-variables-in-g ?

Comment: vtable only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191678/print-c-vtables-using-gdb

Answer (score 27, accepted):

g++ -fdump-class-hierarchy -c source_file.cpp

Comment: Note that in g++ 8 this flag was switched to _-fdump-lang-class_. This also works for g++ 9. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Developer-Options.html