# How to set default options for gdb?

Tags: gdb

I have several options that I set every time I open GDB, for instance:

```
set print thread-events off
```

Is there a way to set these options by default, perhaps something like a .gdb_rc file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The initialization file for `gdb` is called `.gdbinit`. You can put your desired options in this file. They'll be automatically executed during gdb's startup.

Example content:

```
# set command line argument to "2"
set args 2
```

You may put the `.gdbinit` file into your $HOME or current directory. The latter overrides the settings in the global `$HOME/.gdbinit` file.

Comment: Great, never have to type `catch throw` again!

Comment: How do you add the `/m` option as a default for `disassemble` into the `.gdbinit` file?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this: set disassembly-flavor intel