# instantiated class of an object

Tags: c++, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am debugging a c++ program with gdb in eclipse. How can I now the exact class of an object?
Let's say I am debugging a method

```
void foo(Instruction *I){
  I->bar();
}
```

Let's say also that `Instruction` has a lot of subclasses. how can I know which subclass of `Instruction` instantiates object `I`?

Comment: Give your subclass Tag fields. It can be just simple enum. Set them in each subclass's constructors.

Comment: I am searching for a solution within GDB, without modifying the code

Comment: Can you dynamic_cast in gdb's command line? Otherwise, find a vptr?

Comment: I can dynamic cast in gdb, but, since the sublasses are more than 50, it would be cumbersome.
What is vptr?

Comment: I know visual studio show you this information. There should be something similar in eclipse.

Comment: As identified by [this q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528979/how-to-determine-whether-an-object-is-an-instance-of-certain-c-class-in-gdb) use the gdb command `set print object on` so that when you invoke `ptype I` the derived class will be identified.

Answer (score 0):

You want "set print object on".  This will use the RTTI information to print the full object.

This should be the default; hopefully it will be eventually.