# How to obtain derived class information from a base class pointer in GDB via Python

Tags: python, c++, types, gdb, superclass

This is the same question as [How to determine if an object is an instance of certain derived C++ class from a pointer to a base class in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528979/how-to-determine-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-certain-derived-c-class-from-a) but to do the same from the gdb extension in Python.

Given the same example shown in an answer to that question:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyBase {
public:
  virtual int myMethod() = 0;
};

class MyDerived1 : public MyBase {
public:
  virtual int myMethod() { return 1; }
};

class MyDerived2 : public MyBase {
public:
  virtual int myMethod() { return 2; }
};

int main() {
  MyBase *myBase;
  MyDerived1 myDerived1;
  MyDerived2 myDerived2;
  myBase = &myDerived1;
  std::cout << myBase->myMethod() << std::endl;
  myBase = &myDerived2;
  std::cout << myBase->myMethod() << std::endl;
}
```

As mentioned in the response, I can do:

```
(gdb) b 24
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400a19: file derived.cc, line 24.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/ubuntu/c-test/derived/derived
1

Breakpoint 1, main () at derived.cc:24
24        myBase = &myDerived2;
(gdb) p *myBase
$1 = {_vptr.MyBase = 0x400c00 <vtable for MyDerived1+16>}
(gdb) set print object on
(gdb) p *myBase
$2 = (MyDerived1) {<MyBase> = {_vptr.MyBase = 0x400c00 <vtable for MyDerived1+16>}, <No data fields>}
```

So I can see that this is an instance of MyDerived1.  But in Python, I get the following.

```
(gdb) python-interactive
>>> myBase = gdb.parse_and_eval("myBase")
>>> str(myBase.type)
'MyBase *'
```

How can I obtain the actual class in Python extension?  The real objective here is to be able to cast the instance to the right derived class so I can pretty print the information specific to that derived class.

Answer (score 1):

I can use the attribute `dynamic_type` as documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html):

> — Variable: Value.dynamic_type
>
> The dynamic type of this gdb.Value. This uses C++ run-time type
> information (RTTI) to determine the dynamic type of the value. If this
> value is of class type, it will return the class in which the value is
> embedded, if any. If this value is of pointer or reference to a class
> type, it will compute the dynamic type of the referenced object, and
> return a pointer or reference to that type, respectively. In all other
> cases, it will return the value's static type.
>
> Note that this feature will only work when debugging a C++ program
> that includes RTTI for the object in question. Otherwise, it will just
> return the static type of the value as in ptype foo (see ptype).

So, I can get the derived class with:

```
>>> str(myBase.dynamic_type)
'MyDerived1 *'
```

Comment: Thank you for this great pointer.  First, the current URL to the "dynamic_type" documentation is https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html. Second, here is how I extracted a derived class name from a base pointer from within a GDB/Python custom command script: "derived=gdb.parse_and_eval("*((My_Base_Class*)0x1006256700)").dynamic_type".  <derived> is set to "class My_Derived_Class". gdb.parse_and_eval() returns a gdb.Value, off of which you can call "dynamic_type".