# Why is an abstract virtual base class with no data member more efficient for multi-inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I'm reading the book *Inside C++ Object Model* and learning about the model of virtual multi-inheritance.

I know that we need insert two kinds of information into each part of base class in a derived class object:
virtual function and virtual base class.

The book proposed two strategies:
1)Two pointers. One for virtual function, the other for virtual base class.
[image]

2) One pointer pointing at one table, which contains virtual function slots and virtual base class offsets. We use negative numbers to present the virtual base class offsets.
[image]

I think nothing's wrong just now.

Then the book says:

> In general, the most efficient use of a virtual base class is that of
>   an abstract virtual base class with no associated data members.

[image]
I don't know why no data members in an abstract virtual base class can be more efficient.

The book online is [here](http://csukuangfj.github.io/pdf/programming/inside.the.c++.object.model.pdf). Page 68 - 74 to know about more detail about my question.

Comment: Where is the evidence?

Comment: @EdHeal  I added three captures.

Comment: I think you should add "for multi-inheritance", as subject is pretty misleading without mentioning that.

Comment: This look like some quite tiresome design. Also, why would Point3D inherit from Point2D? That would mean that every Point3D is a Point2D. Makes only sense if you consider them to be nothing but data holders, but not true classes with a concept and all. And why do they use pointers?

Comment: @Aziuth  It is just an example, I know this example is weird. The book used it.

Comment: As an aside, you might find these compiler options helpful: MSVC's [`/d1reportSingleClassLayoutX`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2007/05/17/diagnosing-hidden-odr-violations-in-visual-c-and-fixing-lnk2022/) and the undocumented full version `/d1reportAllClassLayout`, Clang's [`-Xclang -fdump-record-layouts`](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/12/17/dumping-a-c-objects-memory-layout-with-clang/), and GCC's [`-fdump-class-hierarchy`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549618/is-there-any-g-option-to-dump-class-layout-and-vtables). You can use them to see how compilers do it in practice.

Comment: (Note that for `/d1reportSingleClassLayoutX`, you have to replace `X` with the name of the class whose layout you want to dump.)